# Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS server "The repository is not signed"

Tags: ubuntu, server, apt, ubuntu-18.04

I can not update the Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS server newly installed. "The repository is not signed"

```
lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:         18.04
Codename:     bionic
```

When run `sudo apt update` it shows (all repositories):

```
N: See the apt-secure (8) man page for details on creating repositories and configuring users.
N: You can not update from a repository like this in a secure way and therefore it is disabled by default.
E: The repository "http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease" is not signed.
E: Failed to obtain http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease 403 Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
```

Whe run `curl http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/` o `curl http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease` I get the content. Proves that if I have access to the repositories from the server.

I appreciate your help, what can I do to update my server?

Comment: This should be posted to SuperUser or the Unix StackExchange, not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION connect the server to another network, very strange that in the network that this let me download the content with `curl` but will not let update with `apt`

Answer (score -1):

Hi @Wilfred This might be happen due to the unused files and packages so just remove the unused files and packages using 'sudo apt-get autoremove --purge' and retry your update command.

Comment: hi thanks for your answer, the installation of ubuntu in new, I have not added another repository, it only has the default repositories. With those repositories by default I'm trying to update.

If you have any other suggestions, I would give it a lot